# Dividing the values of one rasters on a cell-by-cell basis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, raster-conversion, error-000539, arcgis-10.5

I have been trying to divide an ArcGIS (ver 10.5) generated raster layer by a constant and continue to receive errors (Error - 000539).

My first attempt was to simply divide the raster by my constant (3020) - error
[image]

My second attempt was to create a copy of the "kernel" grid and reclassify it giving each cell a value of 3020 which failed too.  Same error 000539

[image]

Lastly out of frustration I exported the grid and performed the operation in R. Which worked fine.  Anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong within Raster Calculator.

Comment: Set extent to it, define output as grid in folder not fgdb raster

Comment: Did you review our [self-assembling FAQ on ERROR 000539](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000539?sort=frequent)?

Comment: Yes this appears to be the reason.  Thought it might have something to do with bit depth 8 Bit verse 32 Bit.  But apparently not.  How might I have know  this, there doesn't appear to be anything addressing this in the ArcGIS doc.

Comment: Just an idea, as the calculation is very simple why not use the Divide tool in Spatial Analyst?

Comment: Yes I could have used this but the equation becomes more complicated.  I also think there is an issue with how ArcGIS is installed on my Windows 10 computer as I didn't have any problems at work using a fgdbr file.